# Do different languages process regular expression differently?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

The following regular expression is valid in Python, as demonstrated:

```
>>> pattern = "[a-z]"
>>> re.findall(pattern,"a")
['a']
```

In Javascript however, the equivalant code does not produce the result:

```
pattern = /'[a-z]'/
pattern.test('a')
false
```

How could this be? It is exactly the same regex code, which leads me to believe there is some difference in the way the languages process it. Is this the case?

Comment: probably because Javascript doesn't need double quotes.

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work.

Comment: No quotes at all in the pattern!! In javascript, only the slashes are needed to delimit a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have literal quotes in your pattern.  Your pattern will match `"'a'"` but not `"a"`.

So don't write

```
pattern = /'[a-z]'/
```

rather do

```
pattern = /[a-z]/
```

or

```
pattern = new RegExp("[a-z]")
```

Use `var pattern` in assignment if you don't want `pattern` to be global.